# How do I change the font style of the mathematical symbols in the figure?

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex, figure

In the overleaf file, I have used the following package

```
\usepackage[cal=boondoxupr,
calscaled=.94,
bb=libus,
frak=mma,
frakscaled=.97,
scr=zapfc]{mathalpha}
```

So for lowercase symbols, I used \mathcal and for uppercase, \mathscr. But how do I change the symbols from the figure to the same font style? The figure is in EPS format, obtained from Matlab.

I tried \mathcal in the figure in Matlab with the latex interpretor, but it just gives the default font style for uppercase symbols and doesn't work for lowercase. So how do I change the uppercase symbols in the figure to zapfc style and the lowercase to boondoxpur style?

Comment: You may want to show a [mcve] of the MATLAB figure

Comment: You could use the psfrag package to replace some placeholder text with whatever latex code you like.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time, psfrag package did it for me.